# OSX call method from another NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, nswindow

I am beginner in OSX development. I developed iOS app. In my storyboard I designed UI but I want synchronize all `NSViewController` with main `ViewController`. For example I want to call method from `AddSupplierController` to `ViewController`. How is it possible? Or how can I get `ViewController` in `AddSupplierController`?

Thank you

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: You could link your view controllers as IBOutlets so your `Add Supplier Controller` could call methods on `View Controller`. In details: `Add Supplier Controller` would have an `IBOutlet` to your `View Controller`.

Comment: You could define a segue from `ViewController` to `AddSupplierController`, present the latter as sheet and use a reference type via Cocoa bindings to modify the contents of the text fields or use the `presentingViewController` property to get a reference to `ViewController` and send data back. In OSX this is easier than in iOS.

Comment: @Alex how can I add IBOutlet from `Add Supplier Controller` to `View Controller`?

Comment: @vadian I tried in `Add Supplier Controller` call `self.presentingViewController` but it show me only Add Supplier Controller

Comment: Did you define the segue (as sheet) and call `performSegueWithIdentifier` from `ViewController` ?

Comment: @vadian but I want open this `Add Supplier Controller` from Main Menu.

Comment: If you want to pass data easily between the controllers they must have a reference relationship. You could connect the menu item actions to First Responder and capture them in `ViewController` or `AppDelegate`. The appearance is the same as calling them directly but you get the necessary relationship. Of course you can use `NSNotification` to exchange data but this is the way when you have no other choice at all.

Comment: @vadian Sorry about my lack of knowledge, but I dont know how can I connect it. Do you have any example or tutorial?

Comment: It's very easy: Create the `IBAction` method with a meaningful name in `ViewController` or `AppDelegate` and connect (control-drag) the `NSMenuItem` action to First Responder (the red cube) rather than to the owner or the app delegate blue cube. In the list of methods you will find your method. The purpose of connecting to First Responder is that there is no fixed connection. The first object in the responder chain which implements this particular method will execute the method.

Comment: @vadian thank you so much ;)